# Doubtful answer for conditional probability question

Tags: probability

There's a traffic light in a city which works properly, but sometimes it is faulty. If it functions properly today, there is a 95% chance that it will not malfunction tomorrow. However, if it is faulty one day, there is a 98% chance it is not operational the next day as well.

On average, on how many days is it faulty each year, assuming that a year consists of 365 days.

My strategy is as follows:

P(FN|WT) = 0.95 (functioning the next day if it works today)

P(MN|WT) = 0.05 (malfunction the next day if it works today)

P(MN|FT) = 0.98 (malfunction the next day if it already faulty today)

P(FN|FT) = 0.02 (functioning the next day if it is faulty today)

My solution is as follows:
$$
P(MN)= P(MN|WT)\times P(MN|FT)
=0.98 \times 0.02 \times 365 
$$

Hence, I figure that there would be only 7 days. I'm not sure whether I'm on the right track, though something tells me I'm very wrong. What's more, I'm not skilled in this field of mathematics.

Could you help me verify the answer?

Comment: Are you studying Markov chains?

Comment: Just learning to @mitchus

Comment: Well, this is the perfect example to learn. The situation can be modeled by a Markov chain with 2 states, and the answer you are looking for is called the [stationary distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions).

Comment: I added a Markov-chain approach to my answer.

Comment: @mitchus taking me a while to grab hold of the ideas but no doubt this is an excellent opportunity to learn further about Markov processes

Comment: @BrianTung cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to disregard the year, and think only about the long-term behavior of the traffic signal: It works for a bunch of days, then it's faulty for a bunch of days, and then it works for a bunch of days, and then it's faulty for a bunch of days, and so on.

The lengths of those intervals are completely independent of one another, so if one can find the average length of a working interval $W$, and the average length of a faulty interval $F$, the average proportion of days in which it's faulty is $F/(F+W)$.  *Then* one can multiply that fraction by $365$ to get the average number of days each year that the signal is faulty.

When it works, it generally continues to work, but it has a $5$ percent chance of failing, each day.  So there's a $0.95$ probability it works for at least two days, a $0.95^2$ probability it works for at least three days, and a $0.95^{k-1}$ probability that it works for at least $k$ days.  This is a so-called geometric distribution, and the average duration is $1/0.05 = 20$ days.

Similarly, the average duration of the faulty period is $1/0.02 = 50$ days.

So the proportion of days that the signal is faulty is $50/70 = 5/7$, and the average number of days in a ($365$-day) year that it's faulty is $(365)(5/7) = 1825/7 = 260\frac{5}{7}$.

ETA: Here's a Markov-chain approach to the same question.  There are two states, $0$ and $1$, depending on whether the signal is faulty ($0$) or working ($1$).  The transition probabilities are

$$
p_{00} = 0.98 \\
p_{01} = 0.02 \\
p_{10} = 0.05 \\
p_{11} = 0.95
$$

The equilibrium equation is

$$
P_0 p_{01} = P_1 p_{10}
$$
$$
P_0 (0.02) = P_1 (0.05)
$$
$$
P_1 = \frac{2}{5} P_0
$$

which, in conjunction with the constraint $P_0+P_1 = 1$, yields $P_0 = 5/7$, and we can conclude as before.

Comment: That's a pretty faulty light!

Comment: Impressive answer. Detailed and not to mention thorough. Appreciate the aid. @briantung